# How to get data from an XML File in C# using XMLDocument class?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Good Evening All, and happy weekend!.

I have been trying all day to understand how to parse my simple XML file so I can understand it enough to write a personal project I want to work on.

I have been reading articles on this site and others but cannot get past where I am :(

My XML Document is ...

```
<XML>
  <User>
    <ID>123456789</ID>
    <Device>My PC</Device>
  </User>
  <History>
    <CreationTime>27 June 2013</CreationTime>
    <UpdatedTime>29 June 2013</UpdatedTime>
    <LastUsage>30 June 2013</LastUsage>
    <UsageCount>103</UsageCount>
  </History>
  <Configuration>
    <Name>Test Item</Name>
    <Details>READ ME</Details>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>   
  </Configuration>
</XML>
```

I am trying to get the value in the details element (READ ME). Below is my code

```
// Start Logging Progress
Console.WriteLine("Test Application - XML Parsing and Creating");
Console.ReadKey();

// Load XML Document
XmlDocument MyDoc = new XmlDocument();  MyDoc.Load(@"E:\MyXML.XML");

// Select Node
XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("XML/Configuration/Details");

// Output Node Value
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Details: ", MyNode.Value));

// Pause
Console.ReadKey();
```

My console application is running and outputing "Target: " but not giving me the detail within the element.

Can somebody see why this is happening, and perhaps give me advice if I am completely off the wheel? I have no previous knowledge in reading XML files; hence where I am now :)

Thanks! Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the your XPATH expression

```
// Select Node
XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("XML/Configuration/Details");
```

your are selection an element so the type of the MyNode will be `XmlElement` but the `Value` of an `XmlElement` is always `null` (see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx)) so you need to use [XmlElement.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx) or  [XmlElement.InnerXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml.aspx) isntead.

So the changed your code to

```
// Output Node Value
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Details: ", MyNode.InnerText));
```

Or you can select the content of an element with using the XPATH `text()` function, in this case MyNode will be `XmlText` where you get its value with `Value`:

```
// Select Node
XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("XML/Configuration/Details/text()");

// Output Node Value
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Details: ", MyNode.Value));
```

As a sidenote if you are anyway learning XML manipulation in C# you should check out [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) which is another/newer way to working with XML in C#.

Comment: Hi Nemesv, thanks for your reply; that seems to pull back the correct text. I will take a look at LINQ to XML as well to see which one to go for. It seems the community is quite divided around 3 different methods. My thought going for this method was that I would not be pulling back large XML files so dont need added complexity. And knowing microsoft in the past (XNA *Cough*) I am nervous about getting to indebted to their newer technologies for fear they will radically change or disappear :(

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, a little-known "simple" syntax is this:

```
XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
myDoc.Load(@"D:\MyXML.XML");

string details = myDoc["XML"]["Configuration"]["Details"].InnerText;
```

Note that this (and the XPath approach) could go pop if your XML doesn't conform to the structure you're expecting, so you'd ideally put some validation in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Xpath library for that (u must include "System.Xml.XPath"):

```
 XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
         document.Load("MyXml.xml");
         XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

        foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//Details"))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(nav.Value);

        }
```

the above code iterate over every node called (Details) extracting information and print it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a particular value from an XML file

```
 XmlDocument _LocalInfo_Xml = new XmlDocument();
            _LocalInfo_Xml.Load(fileName);
            XmlElement _XmlElement;
            _XmlElement = _LocalInfo_Xml.GetElementsByTagName("UserId")[0] as XmlElement;
            string Value = _XmlElement.InnerText;
```

Value contains the text value